# jQuery to show or hide div depending on scoll position

Tags: jquery

I need to create a jQuery script to show and hide divs dependant on the scroll position.

For example:

On a page I will have three equally divided horizontal sections (potentially have more than 3 on different pages). On the right of each section I will have a "contact us" box. However I don't want to simply put the contact-us box on every section. Instead when the user scrolls, I want this contact us box to disappear from section 1, and appear on section two, etc etc as they scroll down the page.

I will have this one 5 different pages, each page will have different number of horizontal sections. Some might have 2, some might have 5, some 3.. etc.

So far I have come up with the below code, but it only works for Div1 & 2, i'm unsure why div3 does not show up after I scroll past 250px from top.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150 ){
    $("#div1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#div2").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#div3").css('visibility', 'hidden');

}
 else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250 ){
        $("#div1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div3").css('visibility', 'visible');
 } 
else {
 $("#div1").css('visibility', 'visible');
 $("#div2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 $("#div3").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 }

});
```

The jSfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/FQgT3/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because the condition where div3 gets visible never gets hit, When you're over 250, youre also over 150, so the first condition is true, the second isn't tested.

this should work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150 && $(this).scrollTop() < 250){
    $("#div1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#div2").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#div3").css('visibility', 'hidden');

}
 else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250 ){
        $("#div1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div3").css('visibility', 'visible');
 } 
else {
 $("#div1").css('visibility', 'visible');
 $("#div2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 $("#div3").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 }

});
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you Vincent! life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FQgT3/2/)

you just need to use `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250)` condition first so that it checks it every time first than check `else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150)` that will do the trick.

As you know if first condition works than else if will not be checked.

so i just swapped the if conditions and it worked

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
        $("#div1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div3").css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $("#div1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div2").css('visibility', 'visible');
        $("#div3").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
        $("#div1").css('visibility', 'visible');
        $("#div2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#div3").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```